# Problem with .html() function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain why this jQuery `.html()` function is not outputting anything?
I'm new too jQuery and cant seam to spot anything, if you can please tell me :D

I'll just include the html, nothing else:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //when the DOM is ready 
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var like_count = <?php print "23"; ?>;
            //Scripts for getting number of comments for this post
            var comment_count = <?php print "12"; ?>

            var thumnail_path - "";
            var time_ago - "";


            //settings on top
            var doindex = 'comments.php?item_id=';
            var initialPosts = <?php echo get_posts(0,$_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>;
            //function that creates posts
            var postHandler = function(postsJSON) {
                $.each(postsJSON,function(i,post) {

                    //post url
                    var postURL  = '' + doindex + post.item_id;
                    var id = 'post-' + post.ID;
                    //create the HTML
                    $('<div></div>')
                    .addClass('post')
                    .attr('id',id)


                                //Script for getting the number of likes for this post




                    //generate the HTML
.html('<table width="244" height="121" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" ><tr><td height="24" colspan="2" bgcolor="#0270B7"><table width="410" border="0"><tr> <td width="404" height="20" class="username"><a href="../profile.php?user=' + post.username + '" class="username">&nbsp;' + post.username + '<span class="name">&nbsp;' + post.name + '</span></a></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr> <td width="51" bgcolor="#Edeff4"><span class="thum"><img src="' + thumnail_path + '" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></span></td><td width="355" height="50" bgcolor="#Edeff4" class="content">&nbsp;' + post.item_content  + '</td></tr><tr><td height="19" colspan="2" bgcolor="#Edeff4" class="content"><a href="comment.php?id=' + post.item_id + '"  class="post-title">&nbsp;<span class="post-title">comment </span></a><a href="#"  class="post-title">(' + likecount + '</a><a href="comment.php?id=' + post.item_id + '"  class="post-title"><span class="post-title">)</span></a> <span class="post-title"><a href="#"  class="post-title">likes (' + likecount + ') &nbsp;' + time_ago + '</a></span></td></tr><tr><td height="18" colspan="2" class="content">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>')
```

Thanks :))

Comment: What are you calling `.html()` on?  Surely it must be something.

Comment: You need something to put the content into like `$('#someDiv').html('<p></p>');` http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Javascript is supposed to *manipulate* the DOM, not create it. What exactly are you doing placing that much markup in a script method?

Comment: the input is working.. but i changed the '.html()' and now its not

Comment: @Brad Christie, I was under the impression that adding to the DOM is manipulating it.

Comment: Please read the [jQuery tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info), specifically the section 'Idiomatic Syntax for Creating Elements'. You should also consider using templates instead of this

Comment: I have added the input above..

Comment: Still, on what are you calling `.html( )` function ?

Comment: @Nick: `document.createElement` is one thing, and dynamic pages for the sake of HTML is another. But I don't see any reason why *that* much HTML belongs in a jQuery call. Especially, from what appears to be, in hard-coded fashion.

Comment: @user663049 Give the answerers some time, deleting the question doesn't help anyone, least of all yourself. If you *really* want to delete the question, flag the question and ask a mod to do it instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you haven't left out part of your script, it doesn't look like you're ever adding your `div` to the body somewhere.

After your `html` call, put `.appendTo('body')`. Example:

```
$('<div></div>').html("Some stuff...").appendTo('body');
```

Of course, you can use whatever function you want to place it in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it output anything?
I'm not a jquery wizard, but I believe if you give .html information (as you are doing) it doesn't output anything, instead it loads that into the item specified.
aka:

```
$('body').html('<h1>TEST</h1>');
```

if you want to retrieve the html don't put anything between the parenthesis

```
var body = $('body').html();
```

*Note: Not tested*

I would look up information about jquery on `visualjquery.com` and `http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='output'></div>
<script>
$('#output').html('<your content>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call the `.html()` function on something.

Check out this link :

- [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Look at my edit above.. it is calling on something, i have prooved the function its calling on is working.. i changed the .html and now its not

Answer (score 0):

I usually add HTML within a DIV by selecting it by its id.  You might wanna try adding the html on another line, selecting the div by its id like that:

```
$('<div></div>').addClass('post').attr('id',id);
$('#'+id).html('blablabla');
```

I've not tested this. It it doesn't work, you can create an empty DIV like Arun David just said before and append the new DIV in.